# How to generate pushId within cloud function for firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I can generate pushId as follows

```
var myRef = firebase.database().ref().push();
var key = myRef.key();
```

In normal front-end firebase javascript function. But I want to generate pushId within cloud function for firebase. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
var db = admin.database();    
var ref = db.ref("YOUR_RELEVANT_PATH");
var newPostRef = ref.push();
var postId = newPostRef.key;
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).